# How do I rename a file via batch using Process in c#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have to rename multiple files on my server. For this I make a c# project in visual studio. (side info: this project has to do other stuff too)
Now I try to call a batch file from that project. This batch file has to rename a file using the old and the new filename.

Here is the code from the batch file:

```
@echo off

set FILENAME_OLD="%~1"
set FILENAME_NEW="%~nx2"

ren %FILENAME_OLD% %FILENAME_NEW%
set error=%errorlevel%

echo %error%
```

This is the code in my c# project:

```
 process.StartInfo.FileName = location;
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", oldfilename, newfilename); 
 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 process.Start();
 result = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

As result I always get 1. Which means that "ren" didn't work. What am i doing wrong here?

The filenames are all in a structure like this in my c# project:  @"C:\test\test\test.bat"

**EDIT:**

I came somewhat closer to a solution. The problem was that I cant pass the double quotes as an argument. I need those double quotes as some of my filenames contain spaces. 
How can I pass those filenames correctly to that batchfile?

Comment: why don't you use `System.IO.File.Move()` directly in c#?

Comment: You need to see the actual error message in order to find out what's going on. Nobody can tell what's wrong from what you posted.

Comment: Your batch script and C# code look OK. Could be any number of issues related to the arguments you're using or the files themselves.

Comment: Do your filenames contain spaces?  You only need quotes around the filenames if they contain spaces.  I think you should be using single quotes and not double quotes.

Comment: do you have the appropriate user rights to rename the file? maybe try calling your batch from the command line with the same parameters as given by your program.

Comment: Why do you want to recreate an existing variable? %errorlevel% is an errorlevel let it be and use it. Also set variables as `"FILENAME_OLD=%~1"` instead of `FILENAME_OLD="%~1"` then `if errorlevel 1 echo something...`

Comment: @MadddinTribleD the script has to be used elsewhere too because it has to be called via ftp for another part of the project. For the second question, I'm testing it in my own directories so I do have the rights.

Comment: @TerryCarmen there are no errors, it just does not do its job

Comment: @jdweng yes sometimes the paths contain spaces

Comment: Did you try single quotes instead of double quotes? The First a last character are double quotes.  Then single quotes around the curly brackets.  Try : "'{0}' '{1}'"

Comment: Yes, but batch does not accept single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem with on a in my opinion 'dirty' way:

```
//I changed newfilename so it's only the filename with extention and not the full path anymore.
string text = "\"" + oldfilename+ "\"" + " " + "\"" + newfilename;

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\test\test.txt", text);

process.StartInfo.FileName = location;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
result = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

As you can see I wrote the arguments to a txt file so the quotes will be escaped.

The batchfile now is as simple as this:

```
set /p arguments=<c:\test\test.txt
ren %arguments%
echo %errorlevel%
```

Comment: i thing you are missing a closing quote (`"\""`) after `newfilename`